# UITableViewCell top and bottom border like ios 7 Settings.app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I need top and bottom line border for the UITableViewCell like it done in Settings.app on ios 7. 
By default there is no border, maybe it needs to change some attributes? Check pls screen how it looks now.[image]

Maybe it needs to add UIView line to Header and Footer?

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is how a plain styled UITableView looks in iOS 7 when the first section is followed by another section that has a header, or when the first section has a footer. If you aren't using headers and just want the light grey bar, you could just add some blank space for the section's footer so the table knows it should draw the footer.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return @" ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler way to achieve this.

1. Place your UITableView away from the sides. eg: using Autolayout
   you'd have a leading and trailing space of 15px (or whatever you
   want). You're now creating the 'indentation' that Apple used to give
   you for free with grouped table views.
2. Adjust the layer to add corners and a border.

   ```
   [[[self tableView] layer] setCornerRadius:5.0f];
   [[[self tableView] layer] setBorderWidth:0.5f];
   [[[self tableView] layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
   ```